# Objectionjs withGraphJoined groupBy and orderBy occurence

Tags: sql, nestjs, knex.js, objection.js

I have a Nestjs app that runs on a SQL database using Objection.js as the ORM

I have these tables:

```
books
id - integer
name - string

tags
id - integer
name - string
```

And they both have a ManyToMany relationship through this table:

```
book_tags
id - integer
book_id - integer
tag_id - integer
```

I have the relationship mapped on the tags model like so:

```
static relationMappings: RelationMappings | RelationMappingsThunk = {
        books: {
            relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
            modelClass: BookModel,
            join: {
                from: 'tags.id',
                through: {
                    from: 'book_tags.tag_id',
                    to: 'book_tags.book_id',
                },
                to: 'books.id'
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I am trying to search for books that have some tags using their IDs.

I'm currently only able to fetch the tags while eager loading the books using:

```
const tagIdArrays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
this.tagModel.query()
            .whereIn('id', tagIdArrays)
            .withGraphJoined('books')
            .execute()
```

Issue is, I am getting all the tags with their related books and having to do the a sort and unique mapping manually using javascript so as to get only unique books and order the results according to the books that have the highest matching tags.

I am also adding an array of matched tags to the books object in my mapping function.

I am looking for a way to do this on the DB level using ObjectionJS if it's possible at all.